# Endian dependent code in real application?

Tags: c, endianness

I know the following C code is endian-dependent:

```
short s_endian = 0x4142;
char c_endian = *(char *)&s_endian;
```

On a big-endian machine, c_endian will be 'A'(0x41); while on a little-endian machine, it will be 'B'(0x42).

But this code seems kind of ugly. So is there endian dependent code in real applications? Or have you came across any application that needs a lot of changes when porting to a different target with a different endian?

Thanks.

Comment: If only all real-world programmers shared your sanity....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much any code that deals with saving integers with more than 8 bits in binary format, or sends such integers over the network. For one extremely common example, many of the fields in [the TCP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) fall into this category.

Answer (score 1):

Networking code is endian dependent (it should always transfer across the network as big-endian, even on a little-endian machine), hence the need for functions like `htons()`, `htonl()`, `ntohs()`, and `ntohl()` in `net/hton.h` that allow easy conversions from host-to-network byte-order and network-to-host byte-order.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Comment: Binary file formats that save integers with more than 8 bits require special handling as well.

Comment: Thanks. I never did network programming before, and isn't it a principle to convert data to network byte order before transferring it?

Comment: Yes, you should be converting to network byte-order before transferring across the network, hence the nice conversion functions that come in `net/hton.h` or `arpa/inet.h`.  Also I would rather use bit-masking and shifts to get at the lower/upper bytes or go between big/little endian rather than pointer casts

Answer (score 0):

I once collected data using a specialized DAQ card on a PC, and tried to analyze the file on a PowerPC mac. Turns out the "file format" the thing used was a raw memory dump...

Little endian on x86, big endian on Power PC. You figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Anything that reads/writes raw binary to a file or socket needs to keep track of the endianness of the data.

For example, [the IP protocol requires big-endian representation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking)

Comment: Thanks. I never did network programming before, and isn't it a principle to convert data to network byte order before transferring it?

Comment: The IP protocol states that all traffic must be in big-endian representation. This means that all receivers just assume that your data is big-endian. If you don't adhere to the standard and you have a different endian-ness than your receiver, it is almost guaranteed that the receiver won't parse your message correctly. TCP and UDP opperate on top of IP, so this assumption propogates to most networking protocols.

Answer (score 0):

When manipulating the internal representation of floating-point numbers, you could access the parts (or the full value) using an integer type. For example:

```
union float_u
{
  float f;
  unsigned short v[2];
};

int get_sign(float f)
{
  union float_u u;
  u.f = f;
  return (u.v[0] & 0x8000) != 0;     // Endian-dependant
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, I agree. This kind of code only work with a specific format, in this case IEEE-754.

Answer (score 0):

If your program sends data to another system (either over a serial or network link, or by saving it to a file for something else to read) or reads data from another system, then you can have endianness issues.

I don't know that static analysis would be able to detect such constructs, but having your programmers follow a coding standard, where structure elements and variables were marked up to indicate their endianness could help.

For example, if all network data structures had `_be` appended to the named of multi-byte members, you could look for instances where you assigned a non-suffixed (host byte order) variable or even a literal value (like 0x1234) to one of those members.

It would be great if we could capture endianness in our datatypes -- uint32_be and uint32_le to go with uint32_t.  Then the compiler could disallow assignments or operations between the two.  And the signature for `htobe32` would be `uint32_be htobe32( uint32_t n);`.